# Why chrome extension manifest v3 sends requests to host without cookies?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, manifest.json

I added host to host_pernissions and content_security_policy.extension_pages: `"default-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://example.org/;"`
I tryed sending reqs with `mode: cors` and `credentials: include` but it did not help.
In developer tools we can enable **show filtered out request cookies** and we will see all discarded cookies:

[image: screen]

Comment: Add the site to `host_permissions` as described in the documentation and use `fetch` without `mode`

Answer (score 0):

Solved, you need set SameSite cookie to None